# Post to Cypress Dashboard after running in Browserstack

Tags: typescript, automation, cypress, browser-automation, browserstack

Currently, our team runs our Cypress tests locally and post our results to Cypress Dashboard. Now we would like to integrate our test framework with Browserstack for crossbrowser testing. However, we would also like to post results to Cypress dashboard after running in Browserstack. I'm having trouble finding any documentation in regards to Cypress Dashboard, and Browserstack. Is this possible, and if so, what does that look like?

I have read the [Browserstack documentation](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-run-cypress-test-automation) as well as many other docs, but couldn't find a definite answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to let you know that when running tests locally Cypress has its own Dashboard to show you the results.

However, Browserstack also provides a Dashboard to view test results in a similar manner as Cypress Dashboard with added improvements.

The Cypress dashboard can be used for parallelizing tests(support depends on the plan) and seeing reports post the build run but users must run those tests on their own infra. On BrowserStack the user can run the tests, see the report, and parallelize (depends on the Automate plan) their tests at the same time on BrowserStack’s infra.

You can refer to the following documentation to help you get started with Browserstack and Cypress:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress

In order to generate test reports for your builds you can refer to the below documentation link:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress/generate-reports#introduction-to-browserstack-cypress-reports

**Note**:- We do not have any official/support documents around to post results to Cypress dashboard after running in Browserstack.